# Hardware game port on Ubuntu Studio 20.04

Tags: hardware, midi

Does the hardware game/midi port work with Studio 20.04? If it does how does it get configured?

Comment: Did you try using it?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Studio can most certainly use the MIDI port on your sound card. You can install the basics with:

```
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-audio linux-lowlatency
```

You probably already have `ubuntustudio-audio` installed, but there's no problem having it here just to make sure. Once these packages are installed, [follow this step-by-step from Khairil Yusof](https://medium.com/@kaerumy/audio-and-midi-controller-on-ubuntu-linux-1058e00bc7d0). He goes through the process of configuring JACK, PulseAudio, and a few other things.

Answer (score 0):

If the gameport is on a sound card, the sound driver should already handle it.

If the gameport is on the mainboard, the ns558 module should handle the joystick, and the snd-mpu401 module should handle MIDI. If the BIOS provides correct Plug&Play information, no configuration is necessary.